# Indeterminate Progress displayed by default in Android 4.0.3

Tags: android, android-actionbar

So I have this small code which enables the indeterminate progress feature:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);        
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

And I know that unless `setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);` is not called, the progress bar is not displayed. However this does not seem to be true when the above code runs on a device with Android 4.0.3. On this device the progress bar is displayed permanently without issuing a call to explicitly set the progress bar visibility to true.

Any ideas why and how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try these

```
supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);           
requestWindowFeature(android.view.Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
requestWindowFeature(android.view.Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
```